# Python Folder Name

Tags: python, file-search

I have a directory in my computer which is having a numeral as the folder name..
For Example, the directory that exist is

C:\3_Software

I am trying to provide the top level directory path.. I want to look into folders, subfolders and files from C:\3_Software, open the file and search for a string. If the specific string exist, then print the file name and the string. So I used the os.walk to iterate over the folders, subfolders and files. Now when it is fetching the directory name, since it has a numeral in the folder name, it is automatically converting to a different format and unable to fetch the file from there.

When i tried to define the 'C:\3_Software' as root and read back the same variable, it is giving me as 'C:\x03_Software'....

And, is there any means of concatenating the root and file path... using the os.walk method..

Comment: Use a raw string or use \\. [Windows path in python](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2953834/windows-path-in-python)

Comment: Try `'C:\\3_Software'` or `r'C:\3_Software'`

Comment: or forward slashes, which work just fine.

Comment: Is there a way to replace all the backslash to forward slash?? I tried to use as  root = 'C:\3_Software' root.replace('\','/')... but it was not working... any clues...

Answer (score 1):

Escape the backslash:

```
'C:\\3_Software'
```

or make it a raw string:

```
r'C:\3_Software'
```

As your code currently stands, you are trying to use character "\3":

```
>>> '\3'
'\x03'
>>>
```